# ASN1 sequence to use in Convert::PEM to read pkcs8 DER privateKey? PERL

Tags: perl, asn.1, pkcs#8

I'm trying to convert to PEM a private key which is encoded and encrypted in DER using pkcs8, with  module [Convert::PEM](http://search.cpan.org/~btrott/Convert-PEM-0.08/lib/Convert/PEM.pm) and it ask for an ASN Sequence (I believe the algorithm used to encrypt is EDE_EDE3)

I've found this documentation:  [Public-Key Cryptography Standards (PKCS) #8:](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5208.txt) which describes the syntax used, but I haven't been able to applied successfully in my PERL code, I've tried:

```
my $pem = Convert::PEM->new(
               Name => "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
               ASN => qq(
                 PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
                    version                   Version,
                    privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
                    privateKey                PrivateKey,
                    attributes           [0]  IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL }

                  Version ::= INTEGER

                  PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier

                  PrivateKey ::= OCTET STRING

                  Attributes ::= SET OF Attribute
        }
              ))or die "New failed: ", Convert::PEM->errstr;
```

**What am I doing wrong?**